# Regex selection in another selection

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

so I have a string like this:

```
var a = " 'asdf'+'asdf'+'we' + 1";
```

I am able to select the three quotes with:

```
'([^']*)'
```

How do I select the start of the single quote(') in the string using regex?
And also a separate regex to select the end of the single quote(')? Is this possible with regex? I will replace the start of the quote with <<.

Final string will look like

```
 " <<asdf'+<<asdf'+<<we' + 1"
```

Comment: I doubt you really need that. What is the final goal you need to achieve here? Change `a` to look like ....?

Comment: @Wiktor: I'm trying to replace the ' in the beginning to << so the final string will look like:

" <<asdf'+<<asdf'+<<we' + 1"

Comment: I know I can use javascript to do it easily, just want to see if there's a way I can do it with regex.

Comment: So, use `a = a.replace(/'([^']*')/g, '<<$1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to replace some part of a pattern only, use capturing group round the part you need to keep, and just match (and consume) those parts you need to remove.

```js
var a = " 'asdf'+'asdf'+'we' + 1";
console.log(
    a.replace(/'([^']*')/g, '<<$1')
);
// And, to replace both ' in one go (notice the ) shift to the left):
console.log(
    a.replace(/'([^']*)'/g, '<<$1>>')
);
```

Here,

- `'` - matches and consumes `'`
- `([^']*')` - matches and *captures* into Group 1 zero or more chars other than `'` (with `[^']*`) and then a `'`. The `$1` in the replacement pattern is a placeholder for the contents stored in Group 1 after a valid match is found.
- `([^']*)` - only captures any 0+ chars other than `'` into Group 1 so, the final `'` is matched and consumed, and will be missing in the `$1` placeholder content.

Also, see the [regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/aFY2rb/1) and [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/aFY2rb/2).

Comment: thank you! one more question, how would I be able to match the ' at the end of a pair? so that I'll get a string:

" <<asdf>>+<<asdf>>+<<we>> + 1"

Comment: @wonghenry Same idea, and your regex already is ready for that. Just use `a=a.replace(/'([^']*)'/g, '<<$1>>')`.